# How do I filter a list of java objects at runtime where the variable I am filtering on is not known in advance?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, predicate

I have a list of java objects, and I want to use stream to filter them at runtime. However, the variable I want to filter on is only known at runtime.

For eg, the user says I want a list of all cats whose fur length is longer than 3cm, I should be able to do

```
cats.stream().filter(cat -> cat.getFurLength() > 3).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The getFurLength() getter however should be dynamically invoked - if the user instead wants to filter by eye colour then I should be able to call

```
cats.stream().filter(cat -> cat.getEyeColour() == Colour.BLUE).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How do I achieve this without writing all possible filters beforehand?

Ideally the user should send something like:

```
{
  eyeColour:{
    operator: "equal_to",
    value: "BLUE"
  },
  furLength: {
    operator: "greater_than",
    value: 3
  }
}
```

and the code should be able to generate the filters dynamically based on these criteria.

Comment: You need to have a mapping somewhere which evaluates what user input can result in what `Predicate` and generalize the statement to use `cats.stream().filter(predicateAsInput).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Deserialize the json into a class containing the three items field, operator, and value. Generate a `Predicate<Cat>` from that by extracting the actual value using reflection to create a `Function <Cat, ValueType>` and then apply the operator to see if the value matches.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Cat` class follows JavaBean convention you could use `java.beans.PropertyDescriptor` to access getter `Method` based on property name.

This allows us to learn what type of value we are dealing with. If it is numeric we can handle `greater_than` and other operators, but if it is non-numeric we should handle only `equals_to` operator.

"Simplified" and very limited solution could look like:

NOTE:
- Solution doesn't support primitive numeric types like `int`. Use `Integer`, `Double` etc. instead.
- I am converting all numbers to `BigDecimal` and use `compareTo` to simplify numerical type comparison, if you get any bugs for big numbers or very precise ones feel free to replace it with proper type comparison).
- for equality check it compares string representation of objects (result of `toString()`), so for Color you can't use `BLUE` but your JSON would need to hold `java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255]`)

```
class PredicatesUtil {

    static <T> Predicate<T> filters(Class<T> clazz, String filtersJson) {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(filtersJson);

        List<Predicate<T>> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String property : jsonObject.keySet()) {
            JSONObject filterSettings = jsonObject.getJSONObject(property);

            try {
                String operator = filterSettings.getString("operator");
                String value = filterSettings.getString("value");
                predicateList.add(propertyPredicate(clazz, property, operator, value));
            } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return combinePredicatesUsingAND(predicateList);
    }

    static <T> Predicate<T> combinePredicatesUsingAND(List<Predicate<T>> predicateList) {
        return t -> {
            for (Predicate<T> pr : predicateList) {
                if (!pr.test(t))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        };
    }

    static <T> Predicate<T> propertyPredicate(Class<T> clazz, String property,
                                              String operator, String value)
            throws IntrospectionException {

        final Method m = new PropertyDescriptor(property, clazz).getReadMethod();
        final Class<?> returnType = m.getReturnType();

        return obj -> {
            try {
                Object getterValue = m.invoke(obj);
                if (Number.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType)) {
                    BigDecimal getValue = new BigDecimal(getterValue.toString());
                    BigDecimal numValue = new BigDecimal(value);

                    int compared = getValue.compareTo(numValue);
                    if (operator.equalsIgnoreCase("equal_to")) {
                        return compared == 0;
                    } else if (operator.equalsIgnoreCase("lesser_than")) {
                        return compared < 0;
                    } else if (operator.equalsIgnoreCase("greater_than")) {
                        return compared > 0;
                    } else {
                        throw new RuntimeException("not recognized operator for numeric type: " + operator);
                    }
                } else {
                    //System.out.println("testing non-numeric, only euals_to");
                    if (operator.equalsIgnoreCase("equal_to")) {
                        return value.equalsIgnoreCase(getterValue.toString());
                    }
                    throw new RuntimeException("not recognized operator: " + operator);
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

which can be used like:

```
class Cat {
    private Color eyeColour;
    private Integer furLength;

    Cat(Color eyeColor, Integer furLength) {
        this.eyeColour = eyeColor;
        this.furLength = furLength;
    }

    public Color getEyeColour() {
        return eyeColour;
    }

    public Integer getFurLength() {
        return furLength;
    }

    public void setEyeColour(Color eyeColour) {
        this.eyeColour = eyeColour;
    }

    public void setFurLength(Integer furLength) {
        this.furLength = furLength;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cat{" +
                "eyeColor=" + eyeColour +
                ", furLength=" + furLength +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
class CatsDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String json = 
                "{\n" +
                "  eyeColour:{\n" +
                "    operator: \"equal_to\",\n" +
                "    value: \"java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255]\"\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  furLength: {\n" +
                "    operator: \"greater_than\",\n" +
                "    value: \"3\"\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";

        List<Cat> cats = List.of(
                new Cat(Color.blue, 1),
                new Cat(Color.blue, 2),
                new Cat(Color.blue, 3),
                new Cat(Color.blue, 4),
                new Cat(Color.blue, 5),
                new Cat(Color.yellow, 1),
                new Cat(Color.yellow, 2),
                new Cat(Color.yellow, 3),
                new Cat(Color.yellow, 4),
                new Cat(Color.yellow, 5)
        );

        cats.stream()
            .filter(PredicatesUtil.filters(Cat.class, json))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Cat{eyeColor=java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255], furLength=4}
Cat{eyeColor=java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255], furLength=5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it reusable with a function.

```
List<Cat> filterCats(cats, Predicate<Cat> filter) {
    return cats.stream().filter(filter).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And then use it with:

```
filterCats(cats, cat -> cat.getEyeColour() == Colour.BLUE)
```

Or,

```
filterCats(cats, cat -> cat.getFurLength() > 3)
```

Comment: Question is, how do you create `cat -> cat.getEyeColour() == Colour.BLUE` from user data like JSON. To quote OP "*How do I achieve this without writing all possible filters beforehand*?"

Comment: Lots of if-statemnts? Don't think there's any ready-made shortcut for something like this as OP is probably looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth: [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) library is specialized in accessing bean properties in a dynamic way.

See [BeanPropertyValueEqualsPredicate](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanPropertyValueEqualsPredicate.html) for an understanding. This is only a solution for equality matches.